# How to parse a string for numbers and words (strings)? IN JAVA

Tags: string, parsing

I have a list of strings that contain names and a series of numbers, ex: "John James Hollywood 1 2 3".

I want to parse out the names using a loop so that I can scan each part of the text and store it in a new string variable. Then I tried to use a conditional to put any numbers in a different variable. I will calculate the average of the numbers and then print the name and the average of the numbers, so the output looks like this:

John James Hollywood: 2

I don't know whether to use the input string stream or what my first steps are.

```
public static String parseNameNumbers(String text)
  {
      Scanner scnr = new Scanner(text);
      Scanner inSS = null;
      
      int numSum = 0;
      int countNum = 0;
      String newText = new String();
      String sep = "";
      while(scnr.hasNext()) {
          if(scnr.hasNextInt()) {
              numSum = numSum + scnr.nextInt();
              countNum++;
          }
          else {
              newText = newText + sep + scnr.next();
              sep = " ";
          }
      }
    
    return newText + ": " + (numSum/countNum);
  }
```

Comment: Delete the words "using a loop" from your question.  Don't specify how you want to solve the problem, lest you stumble into making this an XY problem.

Comment: Please also tag what programming language/environment you are using.

Comment: As a first pass, did you try `text.split(' ')` to break it into individual fields?  Once it's broken into individual strings, you can use `int.TryParse` to see which ones are numbers.  You can use a `List<string>` to save non-number items.  Sum up and count all the numeric items.  Add some error handling to handle the case where there are 0 numbers in your string.  Then divide by the count and add that as a final element to your `List<string>`.  Make sense?

Comment: Also include an example of the output you require.

Comment: @phuzi, The example is the 3rd paragraph of the question, no?  And good call on the language.  I thought it was C# at first glance but I see now that it's actually Java (based on System.in)  (story of my life.)